# shopify checkbox bot working with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shopify, polaris

i am trying to get my checkbox checked when json data for this is true and uncheck when false
works fine with radio but not working with checkbox
its shopify polaris library and angular js for handling data

Not working

```
   <input id="PolarisCheckbox1" type="checkbox" name="name_new_tab" class="Polaris-Checkbox__Input"  ng-click="select_new_tab(\'true\')" ng-checked="data.new_tab==\'true\'" aria-invalid="false" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" checked="data.new_tab == \'true\'">
```

radio works

```
  <input type="radio" name="name_font_weight" class="Polaris-RadioButton__Input" value="1" ng-click="select_font_weight(\'1\', \'1\')" ng-checked="data.font_weight == \'1\'" checked="checked">
```

any help will be great